# How do I detect if thread/s is running

Tags: multithreading, perl

The following is a simple code example I'm working on. It just starts a thread, wait 5 seconds, and then terminate it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub thread_sub
 {
   threads->create(sub
    {
        sleep 5;   # HERE A WHILE ROUTINEs EMULATED BY SLEEP
        threads->detach();
    });
}

thread_sub();
exit;
```

**But the result is:**

```
# ./multithread.pl 
Perl exited with active threads:
        1 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

This because it runs the thread but after that exit without waiting.
So, how can I wait for thread to finish before exit? I know there is `is_running`, but I don't known how to implement it in my code. Obliviously the reported code is just an example to understand how to implement is_running. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

To wait for a thread to finish, one typically uses the following:

```
$thread->join();
```

To wait for all threads, one would therefore use the following:

```
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

Don't detach the thread if this is what you are going to do.

---

About `detach`...

If you had fire-and-forget threads, you could use

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $thread_count :shared = 0;

sub thread_sub {
   { lock $thread_count; ++$thread_count; cond_signal($thread_count); }
   my $thread = async {
      sleep 5;

      { lock $thread_count; --$thread_count; cond_signal($thread_count); }
   };

   $thread->detach();  # Free the small thread object as soon as it completes.
}

thread_sub();

# When it's time to exit:
{ lock($thread_count); cond_wait($thread_count) while $thread_count != 0; }
```

But that doesn't gain you much over just joining the threads, which is far simpler.

```
use threads;

sub thread_sub {
   async {
      sleep 5;
   };
}

thread_sub();

# Periodically:
$_->join() for threads->list(threads::joinable);

# When it's time to exit:
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

Finally, it's more common in practice to create a pool of threads and reuse them rather then creating threads on the fly because thread creation is expensive in Perl. In this situation, detaching makes even less sense.

```
use threads;

use Thread::Queue qw( );  # 3.01+

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 3;

sub process_job { sleep 5 }

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
   async {
      while (my $job = $q->dequeue()) {
         process_job($job);
      }
   };
}

$q->enqueue('some_job');

# When it's time to exit:
$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

I haven't used it, but look into [Thread::Pool](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Pool).

---

By the way, `async { ... }` is just a cleaner way of saying `threads->create(sub { ... })`.

Comment: Thank you, btw, with thread pool creation (last code) I got:
Can't locate object method "end" via package "Thread::Queue" at ./multi.pl line 24.

Comment: Update your version of `Thread::Queue`, you're running an old one.

Comment: @Lucas Rey, You need version 3.01 or newer. // You might want to look into Thread::Pool instead of writing your own pool. (Added mention and link to answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this?  Detaching a thread means that you *don't care* about its return or fate; it will finish and exit or be killed as the program is about to exit.

If you want to wait for it don't `detach` but `join`.

---

As for the question of how to use `is_running`, you need a thread object

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use threads;
$| = 1;

sub thread_sub
{
    my $thr = threads->create(sub
    {
        ## threads->detach();
        sleep 2; say "\tprocessing ..";
        sleep 2; say "\tdone";
    });
    return $thr;
}

my $thr = thread_sub();

while ($thr->is_running) {  # or: while (threads->list)
    sleep 1;
    say "main";
}

$_->join for threads->list;  # instead of detaching

say "done";
```

Btw, a detached thread is also covered by `is_running` (or `list`) and the above works for it as well. But doing that doesn't make sense; I am just discussing the method you ask about.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, yes!  Thank you!  (Need to figure out how to "have fire-and-forget threads")

Comment: As far as I can tell,  when it comes to 'fire-and-forget threads' the answer is 'pretty much never' - there's a race condition 'for free' if your program exits before the thread. And even if that were not so, perl threading model is heavyweight, not light weight and so not well suited for the 'fire-and-forget' thing anyway.

Comment: @Sobrique  Right ... I thought that by that phrase ikegami was referring to a thread model or libraries.  It was actually about his posted method, that implements that. Another great piece to work on :). I somehow don't use threads in production, in Perl (I do in C++). I rarely have long running jobs with a need for pools, or data exchange that'd be too heavy for IPC, and I just don't see why I would use them otherwise -- I fork.  Still waiting for a problem where threads would be a superior solution.